# Selenium for firefox Android

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does Selenium support Firefox Android? If not, does any other tool support Firefox Android automation?

I know that Selenium supports the Android native browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is something that is being worked on for that.  I think it's called [Selendroid](https://github.com/DominikDary/selendroid) .   If that's not what you are looking for, its a good place to start.   Also, in the future there is another project called Marionette but I am unsure if it is yet ready for use.

Comment: i tried Ranorex tool ..but it captures touch events alone and validating the DOM in webpage is not achievable..